# Navigation with modal and drawer

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation in my react-native app.
I've got this in my router.js file --

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
            titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
        >

            <Scene key="modal" component={Modal}>
                <Scene key="drawer" component={Drawer} open={false} type="replace">

                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="HOME" hideNavBar type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="myorder" component={MyOrder} title="MY ORDERS" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="bookachef" component={BookAChef} title="BOOK A CHEF" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="offers" component={Offers} title="OFFERS" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="terms" component={Terms} title="TERMS & CONDITIONS" />
                    <Scene key="mywishlist" component={MyWishlist} title="WISHLIST" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="myaddresses" component={MyAddresses} title="Addresses" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="faq" component={FAQ} title="FAQ" type="replace" />
                    <Scene key="aboutus" component={AboutUs} title="About Us" type="replace" />

                </Scene>
                <Scene key="auth" initial>
                    <Scene key="login" panHandlers={null} component={Login} title="Login" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="signup" panHandlers={null} component={SignUp} title="SignUp" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="terms" panHandlers={null} component={Terms} title="TERMS & CONDITIONS" />
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="popUpImagePicker" panHandlers={null} component={PopUpImagePicker} title="PopUpImagePicker" hideNavBar={true} />
            </Scene>

        </Router>
    );
}
```

Now, after login, I want to have the usual flow i.e. to open the app with the drawer. The problem is, I can open the "Home" screen by

`Actions.drawer()` .

But I cannot open the drawer even by `Actions.refresh({key: "drawer", open: true})` or by sliding from the screen. What am I doing wrong, I cannot figure that out.
I'm using `"react-native-router-flux": "^3.41.0"`

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to the home scene after the login, you can call `Actions.drawer()`, but before you have landed in any of the scenes within the `drawer` scene, the sliding from the screen would not work, because your `Drawer` component hasn't get mounted to the screen yet.

As for not be able to slide the drawer out, try removing the `type="replace"` props on your drawer scene.

As for calling `Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', open: true })` is not bringing out the drawer component issue, make sure in your `Drawer` component, you are setting the `open` props, you can take a look at the RNRF's v3 drawer [example](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/v3/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#drawer-side-menu-integration), if you forgot to setting the `open` props, your Actions.refresh will update the `navigationState` but won't be able to control the open/close state of the drawer component.